# C++ operator overloading?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
class R
{
    public:
    int k, depth;
    R() :k(0), depth(0) {}

    const R&  operator=( const R & r )
    {
        if( this != &r )
        { 
            k = r.k; 
            depth = r.depth+1; 
        }
        return r;
    }
};

int main()
{
    R r1, r2, r3;
    r1 = r2 = r3;
    printf( "%d %d %d\n",
           r1.depth, r2.depth, r3.depth );
}
```

I don't get what the method const R&  operator=( const R & r ) is doing. From it's signature to what it is doing. Is this operator overloading? What is it trying to do? What is the output of this? I admit that I haven't done C++ in a while.

Comment: That's explained in any halfway-decent C++ book, but you guessed right, it's an overloaded operator.

Comment: Its also thoroughly explain on this site:[`[cpp] operator overloading`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) in the search box and read the #1 ranked result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't get what the method `const R& operator=( const R & r )` is doing.

It gets called when you assign one `R` to another, like

```
r1 = r2 = r3;
```

In the function, `this` corresponds to the LHS of the operator and the `r` corresponds to the RHS of the operator.

> From it's signature to what it is doing.

It defines an overloaded operator function for the assignment operator, `operator=` whose LHS is an object of type `R` and whose RHS is an object of type `const R&`.

> Is this operator overloading?

Yes, it is operator overloading.

> What is it trying to do?

If the LHS and RHS point to different objects (that is the check `if (this != &rhs)`), it sets the member variables corresponding to `this`, the LHS of the operator, from the values of the corresponding member variables from `r`, the RHS of the operator. Then, it returns a reference to the RHS, which is not a good thing but that's what it does.

A better implementation would be:

```
R& operator=( const R & r )
{
    if( this != &r )
    { 
        k = r.k; 
        depth = r.depth+1; 
    }
    return *this;
}
```

which returns a reference to the object on the LHS of the operator.

Comment: Why is it bad to return a reference to the RHS of the operator? Can you elaborate on this? 

So the output would be "3,2,1"?

Comment: @rexbelia, it doesn't follow standard C++ convention for primitive types. When you use `(c = getchar())`, the expression evaluates to `c`. When you use `r1 = r2`, the expression evaluate to `r1`, not `r2`.

Comment: Or perhaps "0,0,0" because it returning the RHS of the operator each time.

Comment: The way the code is written, the output should be "1 1 0".

Comment: Why doesn't it get incremented the second time? As in "2 1 0"? Also according to my it is copying over r's member variables into this. But it doesn't return this. So each time it is returning itself (what was the original r), so wouldn't the output be "0 0 0"?

Comment: `r1 = r2 = r3;` is equivalent to `r1 = (r2 = r3);`. The way it's been implemented, that is equivalent to `r2 = r3;` followed by `r1 = r3;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68777/discussion-between-rexbelia-and-r-sahu).

Answer (score 0):

It is an operator overload. It allows this:

```
r1 = r2 = r3
```

With each assignment, your code is adding 1 to depth so it knows how many times it has assigned `R`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [copy assignment operator (`=`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator).  It copies the values of the right-hand instance to the left-hand instances (and increments one, which is strange).